# Minimize Delphi Form other than main form to System Tray

Tags: forms, delphi

My problem is difficult for me to explain so please be patient and ask for further info if needed.

I have an app that lets users search for data on a webserver.
That search returns an address that I the do a geocode of using GMLib component.

But loading the map takes som time and what I would like to is to have the mapform load at program start and load the map so it is ready for use.
But I don't want the form to be visible to the user so I was thinking of minimizing it to systray. That way I believe it to be still active and able to do the load.
When needed I then will show the form calling a procedure on it.
And when done I will call another one that minimizes it to tray again.

I am unsure if this is how to do it or there is a better way.

Comment: You don't actually minimize to the system tray. You can hide a form and show an icon in the tray. Then you can respond to clicks on that icon anyway you want, in your case by making the form visible again.

Comment: What about a Splashscreen?

Comment: just to be sure, you want to minimize to the `System Tray` not the taskbar?

Comment: It sounds to me as if you want to start the program minimised, then let the form resize itself to be visible when it has downloaded the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as "minimizing to the systray". For a start it's actually called the notification area. But you cannot minimize to the notification area either. Here's what you can do:

1. Create (and destroy) a notification area icon.
2. Hide (or show) a form.

Now, what people mean by *minimize to the notification area* is simply the two items in the list above, performed at the same time. You are free to do any combination of these things. There is no special *minimize to the notification area* action.

In your scenario, it's not compulsory to create any UI at all. You can do the following:

1. At application startup, create one (or more) forms.
2. Let those forms do whatever work they need to do.
3. Do not show the forms until they are ready.

Simply put, you do not need to make forms visible in order for code to execute.

Comment: I will give it a go and try to make it this way.

Comment: I got something up and running that looks like it could be a solution - thanks